# Dependency on two versions of a Jar

Tags: maven, maven-2

I have a module X that is dependent on a Third party library which in turn depends on apache-commons-collections 2.1.

In module X, I want to use the latest apache-commons-collections 3.0 which has some additional methods than 2.1. If I add a dependency to 3.0, I'm guessing this will create a problem since the class loader just picks up the first class it sees in the classpath. Is there a good way to get around this problem?

Thanks,
S

Answer (score 1):

IMHO there is no **really** good way without additional solution for modularity (like Java EE's EAR or OSGi). I guess however that you're asking about just simple web (or not) module that directly use this 3rd party lib. I'm afraid you have to resolve this conflict manually. If fact, Maven won't provide 2 versions of `commons-collections` and depend on classloader's resolution, but rather resolve dependencies graph and pick the version it guess it's better with your POMs' declarations in mind. That means, if you declare in module X dependency on `commons-collections` version 3.0, that version will be used since this declaration is more important than some 3rd party lib's dependencies.

That's a serious problem of Java Platform itself, cousing such problems like the famous JAR hell. Unfortunately, it is your problem to choose and declare `commons-collections` version that satisfy both you and your 3rd party lib.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the dependency to 3.0 to your project and it will prefer it over the older version of 2.1. To be explicit you can add an exclusion. In any case use the dependency plugin and the analyze and tree goals to see what is happening.

Long story short... this happens all the time and will be fine and in any case you can control what happens.